# SVN showing version as 1:74M and svn log is empty apart from initial import?

Tags: ios, svn, macos, version-control

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong, but I have an iphone project that I have in subversion that seems to be behaving wrongly and would like to know how best to restore things to how they should be.

I always use svn from the command line on the mac, so at the end of each of my revisions, I do something like this;

```
svn commit -m 'my message'
```

And I get back the expected output ending with Committed revision xx

However, I've just discovered that if I do `svn log` I get a single entry which says something like this;

```
r1 | username | 2011-05-13 18:54:10 | 1 Line 
initial import
```

And there is no detail on any of the other commits I have done :(

If I type `svnversion` I see 1:74M which isnt what I expect. I don't quite get what the colon is doing in the version number although I can see the M only appears when I have local modifications.

If I check out a specific revision into another  folder, I get what I expect, so the data all seems to be on the remote svn server somewhere, but something somewhere is confused (including me!).

I have 3 questions.

- a) How did this happen?
- b) What is actually going on?
- c) How can I fix it so I can work as normal and see the full log history etc?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working on a [mixed revision](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re57.html). Based on my experience

a) You are doing svn commits without an svn update (even if you are the only one committing)
b) You probably have only been doing svn commits since the beginning. And if you never updated then your working copy is 1 with changes from revision 74 that are modified (M).
c) Try and svn update and see if you end up with 74 or 74M

Comment: Ahhhh ... it never occurred to me to do an update as I'm the only one working on the project. Yup, that has indeed fixed it - many thanks!

Comment: Not a problem, I actually just learned about mixed revisions myself within the past couple of weeks while trying to automatically store the version number in the settings PLIST. +1 for a good question.